# Trying to edit an entry, but DB does not update

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to update a record in my db. The form renders well and receives the input from the views.py. After submission the redirect works, but the database is not updated with the form data. What am I missing?

#### model.py

```
class Party(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    party_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

#### views.py

```
@main.route('/edit-party/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_party(id):
    party = Party.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
    form = PartyForm()
    form.party_name.data = party.party_name
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        party.party_name = form.party_name.data
        db.session.add(party)
        return redirect('parties')
    return render_template('edit.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Are you *committing* those updates in another method or function?

Comment: @IronFist That's usually not needed in flask, but even if I add db.session.commit(), it does not store the value in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wiping out your updates before updating. It actually updates the DB, but `form.party_name.data = party.party_name` has overwritten your new data.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that worked! I moved the `form.party_name.data = party.party_name` to after the if loop, and the problem is solved